# Using javascript nodejs class method in a callback and keeping both contexts

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I want to use a method from a class as a socketio callback. The method that is called should still have the 'this' associated with the socket as well as the 'this' for the class variables.

Ultimately, this is so I can use this.id for the socket id, as well as using io to emit to all connected sockets. I went through a ton of similar questions but couldn't find a clear (to me) solution.

```
/index.js
const test = require('./modules/testClass.js');
test.init("some string");

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('login', test.saySomething)
})

/testClass.js
class Test {
  init(someString) {
      this.theString = someString;
  }
  saySomething() {
    console.log(this.theString);
  }
}

module.exports = new Test();
```

In this simple example it should print "some string" but also be able to access the socket id. Thanks!

Update:
I was able to accomplish it like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('login', (username) => tables.testit(socket, username))
})

testit(socket, username) {
  console.log(socket.id + " " + username);
}
```

This isn't very pretty, is this still good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can maintain both contexts, but the way I would solve this problem is by using `bind` on your socket.io callback. So `socket.on('loging', test.saySomething.bind(test))`
Now if you also want your socket instance in your class you can pass it as an argument to `saySomething(socket)`. In the callback this will become `socket.on('loging', test.saySomething.bind(test, socket))`.

On a side note. Why use the init function if you can use the built in constructor?

Comment: I wasn't able to get the bind to work properly in my tests. I'm using init instead of a constructor because the class is being instantiated in the export because I want it to be a singleton. Init is called in index.js to pass the io socket object in my actual code.